# What will be the way to read xml here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have this below xml file:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LoanProduct xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Program>
<ProgramID>6</ProgramID>
<Name>Primary Loan</Name>
<InterestRate>0.23</InterestRate>
<StartDate>2018-12-20</StartDate>
<EndDate>2019-03-31</EndDate>
</Program>

<Program>
<ProgramID>6</ProgramID>
<Name>Primary Loan</Name>
<InterestRate>0.25</InterestRate>
<StartDate>2019-04-1</StartDate>
<EndDate>2099-12-31</EndDate>
</Program>
</LoanProduct>
```

In my class file I have to read from xml file and run some query on it:-

```
   String xml = Server.MapPath("/Resources/LoanProduct.xml");
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml(xml);
```

Suppose I want to retrieve where ProgramID= 6 and EndDate = '2099-12-31'
How can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you particularly need it in a `DataSet`? I'd normally load it into an `XDocument`, which makes it pretty simple to query directly.

Comment: No, I dont have to

Comment: Okay. In that case I suggest you read a LINQ to XML tutorial (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-linq-to-xml) and see whether that helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result by using `XDocument` under the namespace `System.Xml.Linq`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Path to your xml file");
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var result = (from program in doc.Descendants(ns + "Program")
              where Convert.ToInt32(program.Element(ns + "ProgramID").Value) == 6 && program.Element(ns + "EndDate").Value == "2099-12-31"
              select program).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialization.  The date should be consistent otherwise you will get an error with this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program1
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LoanProduct));

            LoanProduct loanProduct = (LoanProduct)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "LoanProduct", Namespace = "")]
    public class LoanProduct
    {
        [XmlElement("Program", Namespace = "")]
        public List<Program> programs { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Program", Namespace = "")]
    public class Program
    {
        public int ProgramID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal InterestRate { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```